# How to load URLs in a separate browser from within Samsung Messenger?

Tags: samsung, sms, browser, url

In Samsung Messenger, if an SMS message includes a URL, clicking on that URL seems to always load the website in Android System WebView.

Is there a way to specify which external browser app to use to load these URLs?

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for the same but literally there is no such option.
However, what Samsung's Official site suggests to do it, is:

> If you would prefer to use another browser as default from the messaging app - you can try searching the Google Play Store to download another messaging application. The Android Messages app, for example, defaults to open links in the Chrome browser.

Source: https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/about-the-new-in-app-browser/